# How to properly include code in .rb files into Rails architecture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently coding an application in Ruby that does some simple external API calls to Soundcloud's API.

I have developed a bunch of code inside a single .rb file and want to put this into the rails architecture. This Ruby file has the following classes:

```
class SoundcloudUser
class SoundcloudQuery
class SoundcloudFollowers
```

Currently I understand that I can put these classes into seperate .rb files, and then just put them into the /models/ folder which then gives me the ability to call these classes from elsewhere in my rails application (using require/include).

My question is simply, is this the correct way to go about this? I am familiar with rails, but I am new to transferring a Ruby developed project into the rails format. I tried searching best practices for this in the Ruby style guide but I didn't really find anything.

On a side note - I wanted to also create another class that acts as a ?service? wherein in checks my local database if an entry already exists in the database, and if not, then it will query new data. My side-question here would be similar - where would this .rb file for this 'service' live?

I hope I explained my question clearly enough, if not, I am happy to add some clarifications. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in Rails, you can put them in either `lib/` or somewhere in the main `app` directory. For example, you can create `app/services` and put them inside there, and when you restart the Rails server you should be able to call `SoundcloudUser` (provided you name them `app/services/soundcloud_user.rb`.

I always look at the Gitlab source code for this. It's a gigantic Rails app but look at this file: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/services/gravatar_service.rb. Because it's inside an `app/services` (any name actually), `GravatarService` can be called from anywhere in Rails. If you want to have some namespacing, you have to put it in `app/services/soundcloud/user.rb` or `lib/soundcloud/user.rb` and name the class `Soundcloud::User`.

For the class that acts as a service, it seems like it orchestrates the logic of "check if (song?) exists, else scrape. Some people put it in a model class, I'd probably put it in a service class a la the Gitlab source code. Hope I helped.

Comment: Hey Daryll! Thanks so much for the response. I think I am going to adopt this approach. By putting application logic into the services folder, would that be something expected by someone looking at my code? I also wanted to ask how these services fit into the MVC architecture, i.e. does a service have a controller? Sorry, i'm fairly new to the MVC world!

Also - when you said you'd probably put it in a service class, do you 
Thanks again, I will mark this question as answered

Comment: It really depends, but I think (don't quote me on this) about 90% of all Rails developers have created a service class/object before. (They might put it in a different directory name but it's usually in the `app/commands` or `app/services` directory. So yes, it's a pattern often used. Are you new with Rails? I learned a lot about how Rails apps are structured when I first when to my local user group meetup. Good luck!

Comment: Haha thanks Daryll, I am actually going to my first one tonight (funny you mentioned that!). I just edited that last comment with one more question if that's ok: 
I also wanted to ask how these services fit into the MVC architecture, i.e. does a service have a controller? Sorry, i'm fairly new to the MVC world!

Comment: Sure, I think that MVC is good for a first pattern, but there are layers in the middle. For me, I usually add a service object if the logic in the controller action is more than a simple CRUD action. In your case, I would put the "soundcloud scraping logic" in a service, that way it can be accessed from outside of the controller and it can be accessed in a job. Check this article out: https://codeclimate.com/blog/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/. Hard to explain intermediate Rails architecture in text haha so I suggest ask the people at the meetup for what books to read :)

Comment: Many thanks for all your help Daryll! Much appreciated and I hope you have a fantastic week :)